# Loop in C to make RScript more efficient performance

Tags: c, performance, r, loops

I am trying to compute the number of pairwise differences between each row in a table of 100 rows x 2500 Columns.

I have a small RScript that does this but the run time is (obviously) extremely high!
I am trying to write a loop in C but I keep getting errors (compileCode).

Do you have any idea of how I can "convert" the following loop to C?

```
pw.dist <- function (vec1, vec2) {

return( length(which(vec1!=vec2)) )

}

N.row <- dim(table)[1]
pw.dist.table <- array( dim = c(dim(table)[1], dim(table)[1]))

for (i in 1:N.row) {
    for (j in 1:N.row) {
        pw.dist.table[i,j] <- pw.dist(table[i,-c(1)], table[j,-c(1)])
    }
}
```

I am trying something like:

```
sig <- signature(N.row="integer", table="integer", pw.dist.table="integer")
code <- "
  for( int i = 0; i < (*N.row) - 1; i++ ) {
    for( int j = i + 1; j < *N.row; j++ ) {
      int pw.dist.table = table[j] - table[i];
    }
  }
"
f <- cfunction( sig, code, convention=".C" )
```

I am a complete newbie when it comes to programming!

Thanks in advance.
JMFA

Comment: There is nothing "obvious" when your R code runs slowly, except that  you "obviously" wrote some very poor R code. Try rewriting your code using proper R vectorisation before complaining again that R is "obviously" slow.

Comment: @Andrie: unless you *need* recursion. ;-)

Comment: @Andrie: Thanks for the comment! 
I wasn't really complaining about R..I just thought that doing in C would make it faster...

Comment: Many base R functions already call optimised functions in C. If you write good R, and make use of this, then speed is usually not a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before trying to optimize the code, 
it is always a good idea to check where the time is spent.

```
Rprof()
... # Your loops
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()
```

In your case, the loop is not slow, but your distance function is.

```
$by.total
                    total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"pw.dist"                37.98     98.85      0.54     1.41
"which"                  37.44     97.45     34.02    88.55
"!="                      3.12      8.12      3.12     8.12
```

You can rewite it as follows (it takes 1 second).

```
# Sample data
n <- 100
k <- 2500
d <- matrix(sample(1:10, n*k, replace=TRUE), nr=n, nc=k)
# Function to compute the number of differences
f <- function(i,j) sum(d[i,]!=d[j,])
# You could use a loop, instead of outer,
# it should not make a big difference.
d2 <- outer( 1:n, 1:n, Vectorize(f) )
```

Comment: I think you mean nr = n in your example

Comment: Thank you very much Vincent!
I have a very poor background in programming and code writing so I am still learning the best way to write these scripts!

Comment: +1, but `Rprof` won't tell you if your loop is slow because `for` is "special" primitive.  See the last paragraph of the Details section of `?Rprof`.

Answer (score 1):

Vincent above has the right idea. In addition, you can take advantage of how matrices work in R and get even faster results:

```
n <- 100
k <- 2500
d <- matrix(sample(1:10, n*k, replace=TRUE), nr=n, nc=k)
system.time(d2 <- outer( 1:n, 1:n, Vectorize(f) ))
#precompute transpose of matrix - you can just replace 
#dt with t(d) if you want to avoid this
system.time(dt <- t(d))
system.time(sapply(1:n, function(i) colSums( dt[,i] != dt)))
```

Output:

```
#> system.time(d2 <- outer( 1:n, 1:n, Vectorize(f) ))
#   user  system elapsed 
#    0.4     0.0     0.4 
#> system.time(dt <- t(d))
#   user  system elapsed 
#      0       0       0 
#> system.time(sapply(1:n, function(i) colSums( dt[,i] != dt)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.08    0.00    0.08
```